# How to store html page in xamp local server and use in android app

Tags: android, xampp, android-webview

I am new for android server side..i want to store html page and images in xampp server and retrive it and show it in android app.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

for loading a **HTML** saved document, you must use `WebView`  .

`WebView` can load **html** file saved in your `assets` file of your android application or from special URL like `http://google.com`

i did'nt know more about your question about xampp!

i think saving **html** pages in **Xampp** automatically is another discuss .

Comment: I want to put my html page  and images in server .and by using webview i want to show that html page and by using list view i want to show that image...

Comment: "I want to put my html page and images in server ". i can't know your purpose from this . what is putting html in server ?

Comment: I mean I want to run HTML page nd show image  in my Android app...from cloud

Comment: you must use webview to show HTML page inside android application ~